# CSS div elements overlapped by the bottom div element

Tags: html, css

I have many number of div elements and in the last div element i used `position: fixed;` for not to change the position of the element while scrolling. 
So the issue is some of the top div elements gets overlapped by the bottom div element because it has css like this.

```
#div1 {
  position: fixed;
  background: blue;
  font-size: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pL1s6jpz/74/) Link attached

Comment: What do you expect? %)P

Comment: Adding some padding-bottom to the body element would give you the expected result?

Comment: List of all elements should appear without hiding behind the bottom element.@AjAX.

Comment: [Just add some `<br>` after it.](https://jsfiddle.net/pL1s6jpz/77/)

Answer (score 1):

Add some `padding` on the parent element, in this case the `<body>`:

```css
body {
  padding-bottom: 65px;
}

#div1 {
  position: fixed;
  background: blue;
  font-size: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a19</div>
<div>a20</div>
<div>a21</div>
<div>a22</div>
<div>a23</div>
<div>lastdiv</div>

<div id="div1">
  Example
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @SirExotic

Comment: You're welcome. Could you mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `z-index` to it. Try this code.

```
#div1 {
  position: fixed;
  background: blue;
  font-size: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: It is woring without z-index also.. thanks. Pls post if there is anyother solution. thans in advacne.

Answer (score 0):

First : for **access** to last div , you **dont need id**

**Replace** this code :

```
div:last-child {
  position: fixed;
  background: blue;
  font-size: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
}
div:nth-last-child(2) {
  height:75px;
}
```